# Foreach only showing last item in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm attempting to make a foreach loop to iterate over each item in an array, but it only captures the last item and does not iterate over the first one. I've stripped down the code to only show the relevant parts and added some commands to identify the problem as described above.

```
$message == "kk,ll";
$myArray = explode(',', $message);

print_r ($myArray);

foreach ($myArray as $value);
{   
    echo "$value <br>";
    $array[] = $value;
}

print_r ($array);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => kk [1] => ll ) ll 
Array ( [0] => ll )
```

You can see that when I use `print_r()` the array contains two items. But the `foreach` loop only loops over the last item. Adding the array elements into a new array inside the loop also ends up with an array containing only the last element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `foreach ($myArray as $value);` <- One thing is wrong here. Think about the line and what it does. Otherwise you made some good attempts to try to figure out what is going on! It is just a sneaky typo ;)

Comment: the `;` at the end of `foreach` parentheses is unnecessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two mistakes in you code:

1. In your first line you have two equal signs which should only be one.
2. In your foreach loop, you have by mistake put an semicolon at the end:

`foreach ($myArray as $value);`

Doing this, the foreach loop will run, but the code inside the `{}` is actually placed outside the foreach loop, and thereby causing `$value` only to store the last element of the array.

**The code should look like this:**

```
$message = "kk,ll";
$myArray = explode(',', $message);
print_r ($myArray);
foreach ($myArray as $value) {   
    echo "$value <br>";
    $array[] = $value;
}
print_r ($array);
```

Comment: @CoreyHart  this answer is partly wrong, for foreach ($myArray as $value); will loop the array! And result the $value get the last item of this array.

Answer (score 1):

your foreach just assigned the $value, but output nothing. This is caused by the ; after foreach, same as

```
foreach ($myArray as $value)
{}
```

And after this, the $value have the last element of $myArray, then

```
{   
    echo "$value <br>";
    $array[] = $value;
}
```

only output the last element.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `;` after the Foreach like in the follow code

```
foreach ($myArray as $value)

{   
echo "$value <br>";
$array[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Explain "why" OP has to remove the `;` after the foreach header and what it does when OP has it there.

Comment: it is just unnecessary, and like in the `if(conditions){ instructions }` no `;` needed between the statement's header and the pair of parentheses, at least for a better structured codes

Answer (score 0):

```html
In Laravel Framework Use Code into Controller:

    $dd = $categories->pluck( 'title' )->toArray();
    
    foreach ( $dd as $key => $value ) {<br />
        $array[$key] = '.' . $value;<br />
    } <br />
    
    $cat = implode( ',' , $array );
    <br />
    
 // Result Display : James,Mark,Helmet.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Only remove the semicolon after foreach ($myArray as $value) or used it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31504729)