# PHP Glob not returning all /any files

Tags: php, glob

I'm on a WIN 10 machine. Doing a small PHP script for my own use (not to upload).

My code is:

```
    echo getcwd() . "<br />\n";
    $files=glob("*.txt");
    $log=1;
    krsort($files);
    reset($files);
    foreach($files as $ab => $ac);
    {
    $ac=trim($ac);
    echo "'$ab' '$ac'<br />\n";
    $got=trim($ac);
    }
```

the directory path is correct, however it returns ONE file (there are 3 x txt files in the directory).

i changed it to the following which should show up all the files - including the PHP scripts, but it still only shows 1 file & then stop.

```
     glob("*.*")
```

Is there something dumb i'm doing wrong - why isnt it globbing all the files (or all txt files) ?

EDIT - PHP Version 7.1.9

Comment: instead ofthe foreach loop, what doe  print_r() show ?

Comment: print_r shows all the files - if i change the glob, print_r correctly shows the new list that matches.

Comment: The foreach loop shows the [0] value - the first value.

Comment: so its not the glob at fult

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

It was:-

```
     foreach($files as $ab => $ac);
     {
```

It should be

```
    foreach($files as $ab => $ac)
    {
```

I found the answer here :-

[Foreach only showing last item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773486/foreach-only-showing-last-item-in-array)

I dont know WHY it does, but the un-needed semicolon only displays 1 value/key of an array.

(i need better eyes), but i guess other folk didnt see it either.